# how to do multiple sums in single query

Tags: mysql

let's say that I have this tables :

table num1 :

```
+----+-----+
| no | val |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 10  |
| 2  | 15  |
| 3  | 20  |
+----+-----+
```

table num2:

```
+----+-----+
| no | tot |
+----+-----+
| 1  | 15  |
| 2  | 20  |
| 3  | 25  |
+----+-----+
```

so, i want to select sum value of table nu1.val and table num2.tot in single query

```
 Select sum(a.val),sum(b.tot) from num1 a, num2 b
```

the query is not working
please help

Comment: you are doing cross join... what error you are getting... should give some output without any error.

Comment: check the ans and let me know

Comment: actually, the query give output value. but, the value is greater than it should be

Comment: @RamadhanIlham you can try this it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(num1) ,max(num2) from (
  select sum(val) as num1,0 from num1
  union
  select 0,sum(tot) as num2 from num2)
```

Comment: it's still not working. ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 0):

Join those 2 tables on No column then sum it.

```
select sum(n1.val),sum(n2.tot) from num1 n1 join num2 n2 on n1.no=n2.no
```

Comment: the query work. but im going to select about 20 tables. can you help me how to make it simple ?

Comment: Whatever the no.of tables, we should do join on those table based on their relationship then only will get required result.

Answer (score 0):

select Sum((select sum(col_name) from table_name)+(select sum(col_name) from table_name));
Tested BY :- Rahul Panwar

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all responses. but, I already figured it out

select sum(distinct n1.val),sum(distinct n2.tot) from num1 n1 num2 n2